# How can I launch Safari Terminal on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, terminal, safari

I want to execute some commands for my Safari web browser mainly to disable auto-refresh. And it is seems that the only way to do so, is to use the terminal to write commands. But I am using windows 7 and I am not sure how/where I can open the terminal? As I know that Terminal are used inside Unix?

**EDITED::**

I have run the following command on windows 7 "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Safari\Safari.exe" /enableInternalDebugMenu"` . but the problem I am acing now is that there is no option to stop auto-refresh under the debug menu. I am using safari 5.1.7.any idea?. I have un-checked the "Use multi-process tabs" option, but it did not solve the auto-refresh problem.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a terminal (a couple if you include PowerShell), but their syntax is very different to Unix/Linux shells.  What commands in particular are you looking to translate from *nix to Windows?

To open the normal terminal (Command Prompt), Win+R -> `cmd` -> enter. Also note that Windows uses backslash `\` as the path separator, rather than the Unix forward slash `/`.

Comment: thanks for the reply the command I want to execute is "defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeInternalDebugMenu 1" to show the debug menu. as I need to disable the auto-refersh from the debug menu .

Comment: I have run the following command on windows 7 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Safari\Safari.exe" /enableInternalDebugMenu" . but the problem I am acing now is that there is no option to stop auto-refersh under the debug menu. I am using safari 5.1.7.any idea ?

Comment: @MarkCowan, you can edit your original post isntead of adding details via the comments. Editing your post is preferable here on SU.

Comment: @JohnJohn that looks like some Apple-specific program that you're calling, you'd probably be best looking on the Apple support forums or the Safari for Windows documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The way to disable auto refresh under the debug menu is to uncheck 'Use Multi-process Tabs. Btw, Safari under XP crashes and dumps intermittently anyway, but I sometimes use it because I am a pack rat and have too many open tabs on all the other browsers :-)